# WPF hosting windows forms elements inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf

when putting a ScrollViewer inside a window(not keeping all the window's size)
inside the ScrollViewer there's (with other stuff) a WinFormsHost and a control inside (let's say a DateTimePicker). when scrolling, the inner winforms control keeps being visible when there's no longer a reason (it's outside of the scrolling region), so it "floats" above what's outside of the ScrollViewer

any solutions for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752027.aspx)

> WindowsFormsHost elements are always
>   drawn on top of other WPF elements,
>   and they are unaffected by z-order

I don't think there's an easy solution. You might want to consider having the windows forms control handle the scrolling itself instead of using WPF's ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a solution. Use the following custom WindowsFormsHost class.

```
class WindowsFormsHostEx : WindowsFormsHost
    {
        private PresentationSource _presentationSource;

        public WindowsFormsHostEx()
        {
            PresentationSource.AddSourceChangedHandler(this, SourceChangedEventHandler);
        }

        protected override void OnWindowPositionChanged(Rect rcBoundingBox)
        {
            base.OnWindowPositionChanged(rcBoundingBox);

            ParentScrollViewer.ScrollChanged += ParentScrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
            ParentScrollViewer.SizeChanged += ParentScrollViewer_SizeChanged;
            ParentScrollViewer.Loaded += ParentScrollViewer_Loaded;

            if (Scrolling || Resizing)
            {
                if (ParentScrollViewer == null)
                    return;
                GeneralTransform tr = RootVisual.TransformToDescendant(ParentScrollViewer);
                var scrollRect = new Rect(new Size(ParentScrollViewer.ViewportWidth, ParentScrollViewer.ViewportHeight));

                var intersect = Rect.Intersect(scrollRect, tr.TransformBounds(rcBoundingBox));
                if (!intersect.IsEmpty)
                {
                    tr = ParentScrollViewer.TransformToDescendant(this);
                    intersect = tr.TransformBounds(intersect);
                }
                else
                    intersect = new Rect();

                int x1 = (int)Math.Round(intersect.Left);
                int y1 = (int)Math.Round(intersect.Top);
                int x2 = (int)Math.Round(intersect.Right);
                int y2 = (int)Math.Round(intersect.Bottom);

                SetRegion(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                this.Scrolling = false;
                this.Resizing = false;

            }

        }

        private void ParentScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Resizing = true;
        }

        private void ParentScrollViewer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Resizing = true;
        }

        private void ParentScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.VerticalChange != 0 || e.HorizontalChange != 0 || e.ExtentHeightChange != 0 || e.ExtentWidthChange != 0)
                Scrolling = true;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (disposing)
                PresentationSource.RemoveSourceChangedHandler(this, SourceChangedEventHandler);
        }

        private void SourceChangedEventHandler(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ParentScrollViewer = FindParentScrollViewer();
        }

        private ScrollViewer FindParentScrollViewer()
        {
            DependencyObject vParent = this;
            ScrollViewer parentScroll = null;
            while (vParent != null)
            {
                parentScroll = vParent as ScrollViewer;
                if (parentScroll != null)
                    break;

                vParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(vParent);
            }
            return parentScroll;
        }

        private void SetRegion(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            SetWindowRgn(Handle, CreateRectRgn(x1, y1, x2, y2), true);
        }

        private Visual RootVisual
        {
            get
            {
                _presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
                return _presentationSource.RootVisual;
            }
        }

        private ScrollViewer ParentScrollViewer { get; set; }

        private bool Scrolling { get; set; }
        private bool Resizing { get; set; }

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int SetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, bool bRedraw);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRectRgn(int nLeftRect, int nTopRect, int nRightRect, int nBottomRect);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, and let it be said it have greatly improved the UI in my specific use case, as the windowsformshosts no longer floats below or above the scrollviewer container...  A few issues: Reshaping the host takes some time, so the windowsformshost will "flicker" while scrolling the scrollviewer, and this is even worse when multiple windowsformshosts are present, as artifacts appear in the host control area when scrolling fast. note that if the windowsformshost is loaded while "outside" the scrollviewer, It can "float" until it has been "inside" the scrollviewer at least once.

Comment: Nice solution, though I had to change the FindParentScrollViewer implementation to use VisualTreeHelper to properly find the parent ScrollViewer.

Answer (score -1):

Just add in ScrollViewer control property:

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

and set Height to Your max height. That's all.

Comment: Have you tested this when **ScrollViewer contains a WindowsFormsHost**, as specified in the question? As far as I can determine, this doesn't help; presumably the winform control and the wpf scrollviewer are not properly communicating size with each other. Or perhaps the winform control is overwriting the scrollbar's pixels.

Comment: It was 9 years before your post, I assume it worked in that time.What's the point digging old answers and downvoting couse outdated?

Comment: Downvoting is not personal. I would not waste my time "digging out an old answer"; I happened to have use for WPF when I wrote that. Unfortunately there isn't a "good" mechanism to flag obsolete answers; downvoting is all we've got. [Helps alert both author and readers that this may not be reliable answer at this time.] This is maintenance of a long-term database of useful answers, because I happened to run across this situation myself. You always have the option of deleting your answer if you feel that is a better solution than having it sit here downvoted; that would cancel all votes on it.

Comment: (Note that your answer works fine *in simple situations*, but it does not work in the situation described in the question: *when ScrollViewer contains a WindowsFormsHost*. AFAIK, this has always been the case - for the reason mentioned in document quote in the accepted answer. Its not some later change; you were simply unaware of the limitation when you answered. Hence my comment.)